# Tangent bundle of a quotient manifold

Tags: manifolds, vector-bundles, group-actions

I am interested in the tangent bundle of the quotient of a manifold by a proper and free action but I can't find any reference on the net. 
Does anyone know a book or article where it is described ?

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361151/tangent-bundle-of-a-quotient-by-a-proper-action (I obviously have a vested interest here :) )

Comment: Thanks, I did altough I should have mentioned that the group I am interested in is non compact (being ($\mathbb R,+$)).